# Adding a UITapGesture to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a **UIScrollView**.  I put a tap gesture to it as this:

```
self.tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapped(_:)))
self.tapGesture.delegate = self
self.tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
self.tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
self.tapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = false
self.tapGesture.delaysTouchesEnded = false
self.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapGesture)
```

This works fine, except when the scrollview is scrolling (scrolling animation is happening, not user dragging), tap gesture is ignored.

How I am animating the scroll view:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0,
                           options:[.beginFromCurrentState, .curveEaseInOut], animations:
    {
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, y:yOffset)
    },  completion: nil)
```

This scrollview is scrolling most the time and I am trying to get it to **recognize the tap gesture while scroll view is animating scrolling** ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [UIGestureRecogniserDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624208-gesturerecognizer) functions.

You should be able to specify that both the pan and tap gestures can be recognised at the same time with the following function:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, 
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return (gestureRecogniser is UIPanGestureRecogniser || gestureRecogniser is UITapGestureRecogniser) && (otherGestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecogniser || otherGestureRecognizer is UITapGestureRecogniser) 
}
```

Note: Ensure your class conforms to the UIGestureRecogniserDelegate protocol and you set the gestures delegate so self.

This should work, but I am unable to fully test it right now.

**UPDATE:**

If you are trying to recognise a tap during an animation you will likely need to use the `UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction` option in the options of UIView.animateWithDuration. Used this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686429/uitapgesturerecognizer-not-work-when-i-animate-the-uiimageview) as a source

Comment: I already had shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith method in, but returned true all times.  So according to that, tap should have been recognized while scrolling?

Comment: In theory yes, it should work. Maybe the delegate for the scrollView is setup differently. let me try to replicate the issue and come back to you

Comment: I think u are focusing on a pan gesture from scrollview.  I apologize, I corrected OP above.  The issue is, when the scrolling animation happens, not when the user dragging....

Comment: Ok, I see. what are you trying to get from the tap?

Comment: when tapped I want to get in to func tapped () method.  This gets called fine when scroll view is static.  It's ignored when scrolling animation is happening....

Comment: anytime I tap when its animating.. the animation stops and tap is called. See this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/martinjkelly/9177d75c00f7b59d770cdecfbd7fa6d3) of a single view controller in a test project. (you may need to add an image and change the name)

Comment: Interesting.  I am using self.scrollView.contentOffset = .... wrapped around a UIView animation for the scrolling animation.  Wonder if that has anything to do with it....

Comment: That would likely be the cause yes, as the animation will more than likely take priority. That would of been useful to know at the start :( we keep getting little bits of more information that changes the possible solutions

Comment: Solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686429/uitapgesturerecognizer-not-work-when-i-animate-the-uiimageview. I think this should solve your problem. I've added it to the answer too for anybody else reading this post.

Comment: WOW! .allowUserInteraction worked! Could you please type this in a reply so I can give it "Answered" mark?

Comment: I've put it in the answer above :)